# Installed driver list is not showing in macaca.js installation for MAC

Tags: node.js, npm, driver, npm-install

When configuring macaca.js installation, it not showing the driver list in CMD. Given command as macaca doctor. Installed chrome driver as "npm i macaca-chromedriver". but it is not showing when running as macaca-doctor.
Please help.

Comment: Please help me ...............

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to install the driver o global:

npm i macaca-chromedriver -g